# Sending a request from a deployed Nodejs server to a localhost nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs application that is currently running on my localhost that prints labels from the printer connected to my computer. I am using [this](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) `node-printer` library.

I am planning to deploy this website to a Heroku server. The website will be used by a group of people sharing the same network and printer. After deploying to Heroku the printer functionality is not going to work because the printer is not connected to the Heroku server.

I was thinking of having a virtual machine or a computer on the network that will be connected to the printer. The computer will have a nodejs application running listening to a certain POST request which will have info to print on the label.

How is it possible for me to setup communication between the website deployed at Heroku and the nodejs server running locally so that I can print stuff.

Comment: You have the external server make HTTP requests to the local machine like with any other server-side communication, but the potential security risks are pretty high…Any reason to use Heroku and not simply keep the whole thing local?

Comment: There are 50% part of the website that needs to happen anywhere even if users are outside the network

Comment: How do I make the external server make HTTP request to local machine? If I make the local machine a virtual computer will the security risk still be high?

Comment: You make the requests in the same way you make any other HTTP request. Your local machine will need a static IP though, or some way of constantly telling the online part its current IP. There's less risk if you put everything in a VM but there's still a risk, especially when that computer is connected to the internal network.